# jQuery loop to create divs and append content to them

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, each, prepend

I am trying to create a jQuery loop that:

1. searches through the WordPress post in question for any images or iframes
2. creates a new div for each of these and inserts the image or iframe into the div
3. reorders things visually so that these newly created and newly populated divs appear where I want them (in this case above the post and post title).

I am been trying for over a week to accomplish this, and have gotten close, but something is always wrong.

```
jQuery("document").ready (function(){
   jQuery(".para img, iframe").each(function(){
      jQuery(this).prependTo(jQuery(this).parents(".wrapper940"));

      var ndiv = jQuery("<div></div>");
      jQuery(ndiv).append(this);
   })
});
```

So in the above code, I search for any images or iframes within the .para class, then run an 'each' function on them to prepend them to the post's parent (.wrapper940), and then once they're up there I attempt to create a new div for each image/iframe.

With this particular version of the code, it simply doesn't display images or iframes at all, so I assume I need to somehow 'print' the ndiv element? Have my images and iframes disappeared into a variable and so no longer show up?

Sorry for the roundabout and possibly overly specific post; I don't know enough about what I'm dealing with to be able to ask a more pointed question.

Comment: I don't know what your HTML structure is, but once you create the new elements you have to append them to an existing DOM element.

Comment: You need to change your selector from `'.para img, iframe'` to `'.para img, .para iframe'`.

Comment: josmh - thanks, but that doesn't solve the main problem

Comment: That's why I commented ;) I'm working on answering the question.

Comment: @pmandell - could you be more specific? I previously had this (which also didn't work):

    `jQuery(".para img, iframe").each(function(){

  var ndiv = jQuery("<div></div>");
  jQuery(ndiv).append(this);
  jQuery(ndiv).prependTo(jQuery(this).parents(".wrapper940"));
 
 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are first prepending the img or iframe to your '.wrapper940', but then immediately appending your img/iframe to a newly created div that is not connected to anything.  Your very first operation is completely being undone by the second (by appending it to the div, you automatically remove it from the wrapper).  I assume you actually want all your images and frames to be appended first to a new div item, and then that div item is the one that actually gets put into the wrapper...

```
jQuery("document").ready (function(){
   jQuery(".para img, iframe").each(function(){
      // First I create the div element.
      var ndiv = jQuery("<div></div>");

      // Now I put the div element into the wrapper, instead of the 'this'
      ndiv.prependTo(jQuery(this).parents(".wrapper940"));

      // Last I put 'this' into the div.
      ndiv.append(this);
   })
});
```

Comment: Good lord that worked! Thus ends a week of insane frustration. So fast. THANKYOU!!

Comment: Np man, I've done the same thing plenty of times.  It's hard to see sometimes.

Comment: And thanks for the explanation - it's so clear now that I see it.

Comment: quick followup question: if I now want to target these newly created divs and add a class to the :first of them, how do I do that? Can I do it within the .each, or does it need to happen outside the loop? And do I need to jQuery("ndiv, or this, or the class I added to the new divs")?? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You would probably want to do this outside the loop, but you will need to select your divs somehow.  Once you do that, you can use JQuery's first() function to just affect the first item found.